# Solving second order nonlinear ODE given boundary condition at infinity

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying to solve the following differential equation $$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2} = - \frac{d V}{du} \; \; , \;\; where \;\; \; V = \frac{1}{2}u^2 - \frac{1}{4}u^4 $$
And the given boundary conditions are $u(-\infty)=1$ and $u(\infty)=-1$. The solution that I should get it $$u(x) = \mp \tanh \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) ,$$ but how do I get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
u'' = u'\dfrac{d}{du}u' 
$$
Change of variables $u'\to p$ we get 
$$
\dfrac{d}{du}p^2 = -2\dfrac{dV}{du}
$$
You have now reduced the order to proceed.

Do you require me to go further?

Comment: Thanks, let me work on it and if I am stuck I will ask for more help..

Comment: Ok, I prefer that. You will learn more that way :). Good luck.

Comment: The first step that you made I can understand in this was $\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}= \frac{d}{dx}\frac{du}{du} \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx} \frac{d}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$.

Comment: From this I got $$\int du \frac{d}{du} \left( \frac{du}{dx} \right)^2 = -2 \int du \frac{dV}{du} \Rightarrow  \left( \frac{du}{dx} \right)^2 = -2 \frac{dV}{du} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx} = \sqrt{-2 (V + C)}$$, am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: first point, it is easier to think of $$\dfrac{d}{dx} = \dfrac{du}{dx}\dfrac{d}{du} = u'\dfrac{d}{du}$$. The second point $$\left(u'\right)^2 = -2V + C$$ I choose to have the constant as a positive by convention (tbh). So you are now almost there :).

Comment: I guess that I can now use the boundary condition $u(-\infty)=1$ and $u'{-\infty}=0$ and find $C=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore I have $$\left( \frac{du}{dx} \right)^2 = -2 V + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( u^2 - 1 \right)^2 \Rightarrow \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \int \frac{du}{(u^2 - 1)}= \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{(u^2 - 1)^2}}$$. But the answer for the rhs integral (using Maxima) is $-\frac{\log(u+1)-\log(u-1)}{2} $, instead of $arctan$..

Comment: Ah okay, got it..

Comment: Great stuff Ohm.